# How do I fix an (Errno::EINVAL) error when installing rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I am trying to install rails 3.0.0. and am getting this error during install.  Anyone have any clue how to work around this?

```
C:\Ruby187\bin>gem install rails -v 3.0.0
Successfully installed activesupport-3.0.0
Successfully installed builder-2.1.2
Successfully installed i18n-0.4.1
Successfully installed activemodel-3.0.0
Successfully installed rack-1.2.1
Successfully installed rack-test-0.5.4
Successfully installed rack-mount-0.6.13
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.23
Successfully installed abstract-1.0.0
Successfully installed erubis-2.6.6
Successfully installed actionpack-3.0.0
Successfully installed arel-1.0.1
Successfully installed activerecord-3.0.0
Successfully installed activeresource-3.0.0
Successfully installed mime-types-1.16
Successfully installed polyglot-0.3.1
Successfully installed treetop-1.4.8
Successfully installed mail-2.2.6
Successfully installed actionmailer-3.0.0
Successfully installed thor-0.14.0
Successfully installed railties-3.0.0
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.0
Successfully installed rails-3.0.0
23 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-3.0.0...
Installing ri documentation for builder-2.1.2...
ERROR:  While generating documentation for builder-2.1.2
... MESSAGE:   Unhandled special: Special: type=17, text="<!-- HI -->"
... RDOC args: --ri --op C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/builder-2.1.2/ri --tit
le Builder -- Easy XML Building --main README --line-numbers --quiet lib CHANGES
 Rakefile README doc/releases/builder-1.2.4.rdoc doc/releases/builder-2.0.0.rdoc
 doc/releases/builder-2.1.1.rdoc --title builder-2.1.2 Documentation
(continuing with the rest of the installation)
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.4.1...
Installing ri documentation for activemodel-3.0.0...
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.2.1...
Installing ri documentation for rack-test-0.5.4...
Installing ri documentation for rack-mount-0.6.13...
Installing ri documentation for tzinfo-0.3.23...
Installing ri documentation for abstract-1.0.0...
Installing ri documentation for erubis-2.6.6...
Installing ri documentation for actionpack-3.0.0...
Installing ri documentation for arel-1.0.1...
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-3.0.0...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument - ./</cdesc-<.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something like:

```
gem install rails -v 3.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing?

Comment: -v 3.0.0 means to install version 3
--no-ri and --no-rdoc get rid of the documentation that is causing the errors.

This is simply a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I'm relatively new to rails etc. but the error was gone when I installed the rdoc gem.

```
sudo gem install rdoc
```

Comment: Thank You, your post helped me. There was a conflict with ruby programs. Cheers.